# Castle Windsor not able to ResolveAll when interface is behind 2 abstract base classes

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have slightly altered the architecture of our application, and IWindsorContainer is no longer able to ResolveAll.

This was the old architecture that did work:

```
public abstract class ServiceBase : IService {}
public class TrainFileService : ServiceBase {}
```

And this is the new architecture that ResolveAll does not resolve the FileProcessorScheduledService:

```
public abstract class ServiceBase : IService {}
public abstract class FileServiceBase : ServiceBase {}
public class TrainFileService : FileServiceBase {}
```

So, I've introduced another abstract class....

The code used to ResolveAll for bothe old and new way is:

```
IService[] _services = Program.IocContainer.ResolveAll<IService>();
```

The code used to register the TrainFileService for both old and new way is:

```
<castle>
 <components>
  <component id="TrainFileService"
           lifestyle="singleton"
           service="Blah.Service.Services.IService, Blah.Service"
           type="Blah.Service.Services.TrainFileService , Blah.Service">
  </component>
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you register `TrainFileService`?

Comment: The last piece of code is used to register TrainFileService (IService[] _services = Program.IocContainer.ResolveAll<IService>();). This worked using the old way, but not the new way.

Comment: That how you resolve it (get it *out* of the container).  Not how you register it (get it *into* the container).

Comment: Nothing looks wrong in the code as you have posted it.  Are you sure you didn't change anything else?  Namespaces maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris. You were right when you said nothing looks wrong! The problem was elsewhere. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Chris in the comments, there was actually nothing wrong in the way I had changed the architecture.

The problem was elsewhere. Namely, I hadn't registered a boolean on a constructor...